# GRUB isn't a boot option after rebooting

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, grub2

So I haven't been able to boot into grub since I added a fourth drive to my machine and the drives changed names (sda changed into sdb).

To try to fix it I:
1-I generated a new fstab and deleted the old stuff in it
2-I mounted the filesystem and the esp and do grub-install and grub-mkconfig
3-Run efibootmgr and see GRUB as a boot option (not if I do it before the second step)
4-Reboot and can't boot into GRUB (I have Secure and Fast boot disabled and am in UEFI)
5-Run efibootmgr and see that GRUB isn't a boot option anymore, os-prober on the liveCD shows that it founds Arch

Please help :c

Edit: I forgot to say that after adding the fourth drive I was sent into the grub shell and may or may not have deleted the EFI partition and made a new one

Comment: Please check UEFI > Boot after making sure the drive where the EFI partition resides has the first priority and adjust as needed by selecting Arch.

Comment: @ChanganAuto neither grub nor arch appear as boot options on the bios

Comment: You haven't installed the OSes in the proper UEFI mode then.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I already had arch working for 4 months more or less, everything stopped working when I connected a fourth drive

Comment: Connecting additional drives often changes the order by which the firmware (UEFI or BIOS) detects and enumerates them. It's then the user's job to assure the drive where the EFI partition resides is still the first in order, i.e., as before. Then it's only a matter a setting the OS selection (a different and independent setting) is also set as before to the intended OS (Arch, which means Grub, as before). All of this, of course, is applicable to UEFI installations. For BIOS/Legacy it should be a matter of assuring the same bootable drive is set as before.

Comment: Then you either don't know what I described above, you don't really understand the boot process and the differences between modes and specific requirements (probably not even know what mode was your installation to start with) and in your attempts to "fix" you already ruined the system - adding an additional drive has nothing to do with with fstab, GUIDs (for the system partitions) shouldn't change -, etc. So, we can't really help you. Just reinstall by reusing the same partitions without formatting and then you should keep all personal files and settings, only needing to reinstall software.

Comment: @ChanganAuto ok thanks